# Kubernetes stops working after upgrade

Tags: kubernetes

I am on ubuntu, today I upgraded kubernetes services
with apt-get upgrade; apt-get update. Since then kubernetes stops working, none of the services are running, api-server is not starting. I get below error when i run any command

```
root:~# kubectl get pods
The connection to the server 172.31.139.86:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

root:~# kubelet --version
Kubernetes v1.7.3

root:~# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.0", GitCommit:"fff5156092b56e6bd60fff75aad4dc9de6b6ef37", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-03-28T16:36:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
The connection to the server 172.31.139.86:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

when running kubelet, I get the below errors, it reports no api server running and different other errors

```
root:~# kubelet
I0803 15:27:47.289047   20182 feature_gate.go:144] feature gates: map[]
W0803 15:27:47.289162   20182 server.go:496] No API client: no api servers specified
I0803 15:27:47.289208   20182 client.go:72] Connecting to docker on unix:///var/run/docker.sock
I0803 15:27:47.289221   20182 client.go:92] Start docker client with request timeout=2m0s
I0803 15:27:47.310348   20182 manager.go:143] cAdvisor running in container: "/user.slice/user-0.slice/session-1.scope"
W0803 15:27:47.342781   20182 manager.go:151] unable to connect to Rkt api service: rkt: cannot tcp Dial rkt api service: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:15441: getsockopt: connection refused
I0803 15:27:47.370809   20182 fs.go:117] Filesystem partitions: map[/dev/mapper/noiro--server1--vg-root:{mountpoint:/var/lib/docker/aufs major:253 minor:0 fsType:ext4 blockSize:0} /dev/sda1:{mountpoint:/boot major:8 minor:1 fsType:ext2 blockSize:0}]
I0803 15:27:47.375524   20182 manager.go:198] Machine: {NumCores:32 CpuFrequency:3600000 MemoryCapacity:270376665088 MachineID:95972d262b4e4cc64d46557758b0c9ea SystemUUID:36E3B4D4-D196-FC41-AC15-EABB4D086392 BootID:223527cc-aaef-482f-8871-726f48e853e7 Filesystems:[{Device:/dev/mapper/noiro--server1--vg-root DeviceMajor:253 DeviceMinor:0 Capacity:712231378944 Type:vfs Inodes:44179456 HasInodes:true} {Device:/dev/sda1 DeviceMajor:8 DeviceMinor:1 Capacity:494512128 Type:vfs Inodes:124928 HasInodes:true}] DiskMap:map[253:1:{Name:dm-1 Major:253 Minor:1 Size:274760466432 Scheduler:none} 8:0:{Name:sda Major:8 Minor:0 Size:998999326720 Scheduler:cfq} 253:0:{Name:dm-0 Major:253 Minor:0 Size:723722960896 Scheduler:none}] NetworkDevices:[{Name:enp1s0f0 MacAddress:28:6f:7f:31:8d:06 Speed:1000 Mtu:1500} {Name:enp1s0f1 MacAddress:28:6f:7f:31:8d:07 Speed:-1 Mtu:1500} {Name:enp6s0f0 MacAddress:90:e2:ba:d4:af:94 Speed:-1 Mtu:1500} {Name:enp6s0f1 MacAddress:90:e2:ba:d4:af:95 Speed:10000 Mtu:1500} {Name:virbr0 MacAddress:00:00:00:00:00:00 Speed:0 Mtu:1500} {Name:virbr0-nic MacAddress:52:54:00:1e:95:dd Speed:0 Mtu:1500} {Name:virbr1 MacAddress:00:00:00:00:00:00 Speed:0 Mtu:1500} {Name:virbr1-nic MacAddress:52:54:00:80:4d:52 Speed:0 Mtu:1500}] Topology:[{Id:0 Memory:135105630208 Cores:[{Id:0 Threads:[0 16] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]} {Id:1 Threads:[1 17] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]} {Id:2 Threads:[2 18] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]} {Id:3 Threads:[3 19] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]} {Id:4 Threads:[4 20] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]} {Id:5 Threads:[5 21] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]} {Id:6 Threads:[6 22] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]} {Id:7 Threads:[7 23] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]}] Caches:[{Size:20971520 Type:Unified Level:3}]} {Id:1 Memory:135271034880 Cores:[{Id:0 Threads:[8 24] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]} {Id:1 Threads:[9 25] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]} {Id:2 Threads:[10 26] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]} {Id:3 Threads:[11 27] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]} {Id:4 Threads:[12 28] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]} {Id:5 Threads:[13 29] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]} {Id:6 Threads:[14 30] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]} {Id:7 Threads:[15 31] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]}] Caches:[{Size:20971520 Type:Unified Level:3}]}] CloudProvider:Unknown InstanceType:Unknown InstanceID:None}
I0803 15:27:47.376993   20182 manager.go:204] Version: {KernelVersion:4.10.0-28-generic ContainerOsVersion:Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS DockerVersion:17.06.0-ce DockerAPIVersion:1.30 CadvisorVersion: CadvisorRevision:}
W0803 15:27:47.377969   20182 server.go:356] No api server defined - no events will be sent to API server.
I0803 15:27:47.377997   20182 server.go:536] --cgroups-per-qos enabled, but --cgroup-root was not specified.  defaulting to /
W0803 15:27:47.380752   20182 container_manager_linux.go:218] Running with swap on is not supported, please disable swap! This will be a fatal error by default starting in K8s v1.6! In the meantime, you can opt-in to making this a fatal error by enabling --experimental-fail-swap-on.
I0803 15:27:47.380845   20182 container_manager_linux.go:246] container manager verified user specified cgroup-root exists: /
I0803 15:27:47.380871   20182 container_manager_linux.go:251] Creating Container Manager object based on Node Config: {RuntimeCgroupsName: SystemCgroupsName: KubeletCgroupsName: ContainerRuntime:docker CgroupsPerQOS:true CgroupRoot:/ CgroupDriver:cgroupfs ProtectKernelDefaults:false NodeAllocatableConfig:{KubeReservedCgroupName: SystemReservedCgroupName: EnforceNodeAllocatable:map[pods:{}] KubeReserved:map[] SystemReserved:map[] HardEvictionThresholds:[{Signal:memory.available Operator:LessThan Value:{Quantity:100Mi Percentage:0} GracePeriod:0s MinReclaim:<nil>} {Signal:nodefs.available Operator:LessThan Value:{Quantity:<nil> Percentage:0.1} GracePeriod:0s MinReclaim:<nil>} {Signal:nodefs.inodesFree Operator:LessThan Value:{Quantity:<nil> Percentage:0.05} GracePeriod:0s MinReclaim:<nil>}]} ExperimentalQOSReserved:map[]}
W0803 15:27:47.386826   20182 kubelet_network.go:70] Hairpin mode set to "promiscuous-bridge" but kubenet is not enabled, falling back to "hairpin-veth"
I0803 15:27:47.386880   20182 kubelet.go:508] Hairpin mode set to "hairpin-veth"
I0803 15:27:47.414780   20182 docker_service.go:208] Docker cri networking managed by kubernetes.io/no-op
I0803 15:27:47.443874   20182 docker_service.go:225] Setting cgroupDriver to cgroupfs
I0803 15:27:47.483153   20182 remote_runtime.go:42] Connecting to runtime service unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock
I0803 15:27:47.485332   20182 kuberuntime_manager.go:166] Container runtime docker initialized, version: 17.06.0-ce, apiVersion: 1.30.0
I0803 15:27:47.487348   20182 server.go:943] Started kubelet v1.7.3
E0803 15:27:47.487409   20182 kubelet.go:1229] Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: unable to find data for container /
I0803 15:27:47.487496   20182 server.go:132] Starting to listen on 0.0.0.0:10250
W0803 15:27:47.487532   20182 kubelet.go:1313] No api server defined - no node status update will be sent.
I0803 15:27:47.487837   20182 kubelet_node_status.go:247] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
I0803 15:27:47.489587   20182 server.go:310] Adding debug handlers to kubelet server.
E0803 15:27:47.491669   20182 kubelet.go:1729] Failed to check if disk space is available for the runtime: failed to get fs info for "runtime": unable to find data for container /
E0803 15:27:47.491703   20182 kubelet.go:1737] Failed to check if disk space is available on the root partition: failed to get fs info for "root": unable to find data for container /
I0803 15:27:47.492891   20182 fs_resource_analyzer.go:66] Starting FS ResourceAnalyzer
I0803 15:27:47.492966   20182 status_manager.go:136] Kubernetes client is nil, not starting status manager.
I0803 15:27:47.492971   20182 volume_manager.go:245] Starting Kubelet Volume Manager
E0803 15:27:47.492981   20182 container_manager_linux.go:543] [ContainerManager]: Fail to get rootfs information unable to find data for container /
I0803 15:27:47.492981   20182 kubelet.go:1809] Starting kubelet main sync loop.
I0803 15:27:47.493066   20182 kubelet.go:1820] skipping pod synchronization - [container runtime is down PLEG is not healthy: pleg was last seen active 2562047h47m16.854775807s ago; threshold is 3m0s]
I0803 15:27:47.549343   20182 factory.go:351] Registering Docker factory
W0803 15:27:47.549379   20182 manager.go:247] Registration of the rkt container factory failed: unable to communicate with Rkt api service: rkt: cannot tcp Dial rkt api service: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:15441: getsockopt: connection refused
I0803 15:27:47.549389   20182 factory.go:54] Registering systemd factory
I0803 15:27:47.549675   20182 factory.go:86] Registering Raw factory
I0803 15:27:47.549959   20182 manager.go:1121] Started watching for new ooms in manager
I0803 15:27:47.552051   20182 oomparser.go:185] oomparser using systemd
I0803 15:27:47.552852   20182 manager.go:288] Starting recovery of all containers
I0803 15:27:47.641407   20182 manager.go:293] Recovery completed
I0803 15:27:47.800854   20182 kubelet_node_status.go:247] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
E0803 15:27:47.821579   20182 helpers.go:771] Could not find capacity information for resource storage.kubernetes.io/scratch
W0803 15:27:47.821613   20182 helpers.go:782] eviction manager: no observation found for eviction signal allocatableNodeFs.available
E0803 15:27:52.501201   20182 kubelet_volumes.go:128] Orphaned pod "12c13b83-762a-11e7-af75-286f7f318d06" found, but volume paths are still present on disk. : There were a total of 10 errors similar to this.  Turn up verbosity to see them.
E0803 15:27:53.499008   20182 kubelet_volumes.go:128] Orphaned pod "12c13b83-762a-11e7-af75-286f7f318d06" found, but volume paths are still present on disk. : There were a total of 10 errors similar to this.  Turn up verbosity to see them.
E0803 15:27:55.500440   20182 kubelet_volumes.go:128] Orphaned pod "12c13b83-762a-11e7-af75-286f7f318d06" found, but volume paths are still present on disk. : There were a total of 10 errors similar to this.  Turn up verbosity to see them.
E0803 15:27:57.498812   20182 kubelet_volumes.go:128] Orphaned pod "12c13b83-762a-11e7-af75-286f7f318d06" found, but volume paths are still present on disk. : There were a total of 10 errors similar to this.  Turn up verbosity to see them.
I0803 15:27:57.889786   20182 kubelet_node_status.go:247] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
E0803 15:27:59.501288   20182 kubelet_volumes.go:128] Orphaned pod "12c13b83-762a-11e7-af75-286f7f318d06" found, but volume paths are still present on disk. : There were a total of 10 errors similar to this.  Turn up verbosity to see them.
E0803 15:28:01.499147   20182 kubelet_volumes.go:128] Orphaned pod "12c13b83-762a-11e7-af75-286f7f318d06" found, but volume paths are still present on disk. : There were a total of 10 errors similar to this.  Turn up verbosity to see them.
E0803 15:28:03.500537   20182 kubelet_volumes.go:128] Orphaned pod "12c13b83-762a-11e7-af75-286f7f318d06" found, but volume paths are still present on disk. : There were a total of 10 errors similar to this.  Turn up verbosity to see them.
E0803 15:28:05.500421   20182 kubelet_volumes.go:128] Orphaned pod "12c13b83-762a-11e7-af75-286f7f318d06" found, but volume paths are still present on disk. : There were a total of 10 errors similar to this.  Turn up verbosity to see them.
E0803 15:28:07.500412   20182 kubelet_volumes.go:128] Orphaned pod "12c13b83-762a-11e7-af75-286f7f318d06" found, but volume paths are still present on disk. : There were a total of 10 errors similar to this.  Turn up verbosity to see them.
I0803 15:28:07.976617   20182 kubelet_node_status.go:247] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
E0803 15:28:09.501419   20182 kubelet_volumes.go:128] Orphaned pod "12c13b83-762a-11e7-af75-286f7f318d06" found, but volume paths are still present on disk. : There were a total of 10 errors similar to this.  Turn up verbosity to see them.
E0803 15:28:11.498850   20182 kubelet_volumes.go:128] Orphaned pod "12c13b83-762a-11e7-af75-286f7f318d06" found, but volume paths are still present on disk. : There were a total of 10 errors similar to this.  Turn up verbosity to see them.
E0803 15:28:13.500340   20182 kubelet_volumes.go:128] Orphaned pod "12c13b83-762a-11e7-af75-286f7f318d06" found, but volume paths are still present on disk. : There were a total of 10 errors similar to this.  Turn up verbosity to see them.
E0803 15:28:15.498716   20182 kubelet_volumes.go:128] Orphaned pod "12c13b83-762a-11e7-af75-286f7f318d06" found, but volume paths are still present on disk. : There were a total of 10 errors similar to this.  Turn up verbosity to see them.
E0803 15:28:17.500026   20182 kubelet_volumes.go:128] Orphaned pod "12c13b83-762a-11e7-af75-286f7f318d06" found, but volume paths are still present on disk. : There were a total of 10 errors similar to this.  Turn up verbosity to see them.
I0803 15:28:18.058552   20182 kubelet_node_status.go:247] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
E0803 15:28:19.501567   20182 kubelet_volumes.go:128] Orphaned pod "12c13b83-762a-11e7-af75-286f7f318d06" found, but volume paths are still present on disk. : There were a total of 10 errors similar to this.  Turn up verbosity to see them
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have upgraded to `DockerVersion:17.06.0-ce`. I don't think this version is tested with kubernetes based on this page https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#external-dependency-version-information

Not sure this is causing the issue.

these are the process needs to running in master node. see you can start etcd and API server first.

```
 etcd
 kubelet
 kube-controller-manager 
 kube-scheduler
 kube-apiserver
 kube-proxy
```

Comment: I upgraded docker like a week back. It was all working fine then, today morning i upgrade kubelet and and kubectl and when i made query to my services later, i saw that none of my services are responding

Comment: none of the processes running. Just now i did apt-get upgrade and i saw new upgrades for kubeadm kubectl kubelet after that all the processes are back up again, but i deleted my deployments and all those pods are in Terminating state, this means there is still a problem

Comment: I think Terminated state pods will disappear soon.  if need them you need to re-deploy those deployments.

Comment: Good to know cluster came back.

Comment: It all works fine now, I force killed them and redeployed. I learned a lesson, never upgrade as soon as it's available :). Issue fixed in v1.7.3-01

Comment: looks like i can't ping or ssh to any machine in my network. I can do that on the host machine but not from kubernetes pod. Not sure if upgrade broke it. It was working earlier.

Comment: check your CNI process running. which one your using flannel or weave

Comment: CNI was not running, sorry for the delayed reply